# $K\subset\mathbb{R}$ compact, $K\subset U_1\cup...\cup U_n$ .... finite subcovering

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a compact set and let $U_1,...,U_n, n\in\mathbb{N}$ be finitely many open sets with $K \subset U_1\cup...\cup U_n$. Show that there is $\delta >0$ with the property that for any $x\in K$ the interval $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ lies entirely in one of the sets $U_j$.

How do I choose $\delta$ to prove that this is true? Is it easier to proceed indirectly?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this problem belongs to *Foundations of Analysis* by Krantz and this question is already asked, but I don't remember. So I propose one way to show this problem.

For all $x \in K$, we can find at least one $i$ such that $x \in U_i$ and because of the openness of $U_i$, there is an open ball $B_{r(x)}(x)$ of radius $r$ around $x$ which is fully contained in $U_i$. So, we have $$K \subseteq \bigcup_{x\in K} B_{r(x)}(x).$$
Finally, from the compactness of $K$, the open cover $\{B_{r(x)(x)}, x\in K\}$ of $K$ has a finite subcover. Then, we can choose $\delta$ from this subcover.

Answer (score 2):

**Definition.** Given a open covering $\mathcal{C}$ of $K$, we say that $\delta$ is a *Lebesgue Number* if for any $x \in K$ there is $C \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $B_{\delta}(x) \subset C$.

> **Proposition.** If $K$ is compact, then any open covering of $K$ has a Lebesgue Number.

**Proof.** Suppose that there is a open covering $\mathcal{C}$ of $K$ such that $\mathcal{C}$ doesn't have a Lebesgue Number.

For each $n$, choose $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$. So, $\frac{1}{n}$ is not a Lebesgue Number. What can we say about $B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x_{n})$?

Since $K$ is compact, $(x_{n})$ has a subsequence convergent to $x \in K$.

Choose $C \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $x \in C$. Since $C$ is open, there is a $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subset C$. What can we say about $B_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}(x)$?

---

Can you finish the proof?

**PS.** This proposition works in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. It's exactly the same proof.